# Keytool: Illegal Option for -storepass:file

Tags: bash, scripting, keytool

I am attempting to build a script that uses the 'find' command to search an instance for all .p12 and .jks file types and dump the results into a text document. From there the script should check each of the results against the contents of a generic password text file using the keytool command and the -storepass:file flag.

The issue is that while it appears to be iterating over the pass.txt for each password, it hits an illegal option error and cites a password within the pass.txt as the illegal option. I've attached the code and the error below:

```
#This should search a named directory for the file extensions and save to output file
find / -name '*.p12' -o -name '*.jks' > keytoolFile.txt

keyFile=$(cat keytoolFile.txt)
passFile=$(cat pass.txt)

#This should test each found file against a text doc with generic passwords
for i in $keyFile; do
   for j in $passFile; do
      echo -e "Attempting $j on $i"
      keytool -list -keystore "$i" -storepass:file "$j"
    done
done
```

The error is:

```
Attempting 1qaz)OKM2wsx(IJN on <path/to/file/example.p12>
Illegal option: 1qaz!QAZ2wsx@WSX
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is the value of `$j` different in the `Attempting` line than the error message?

Comment: What about replacing the command line invoking `keytool` by: `keytool -list -keystore \'$i\' -storepass:file "$j"`

Comment: @Barmar I asked myself the same question...I don't know why it is pulling a different line within the pass.txt to fill that spot

Comment: @JardelLucca I attempted the change you suggested, but it seems to be attempting to pass the pass.txt as both the password and the file. Error:

Attempting 1qazXSW@1qazXSW@ on /usr/share/doc/m2crypto-0.21.1/demo/smime/client.p12
Cannot find file: 1qazXSW@1qazXSW@

Comment: I suspect exclamation marks in variables are being executed. Try to add double quotes around all variables and use curly braces such as `"${i}"`, `passFile="$(cat pass.txt)"`

Comment: Make sure both files does not have carriage returns.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the 'illegal option' issue. I was attempting to pass a file that contained multiple generic passwords to test, however, I didn't realize that the command would assume there was only one password in the file. To fix the issue, I pumped the password file into an array and then iterated over the array. I've included the working script below:

```
find / -name '*.p12' -o -name '*.jks' > keyFile.txt

keyFile=$(cat keyFile.txt)

readarray -t passArr < pass.txt

for i in ${passArr[@]}; do 
   for j in $keyFile; do
      echo -e "Attempting $i on $j"
      keytool -list -keystore "$j" -storepass "$i"
   done
done
```